# How do I remove trailing slash from URL using mod_rewrite and send to get variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the below rule which works fine for domain.com/search/term

I would like this to also work for domain.com/search/term;

```
RewriteRule ^send/(.*)$ send.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Two things i would like to achieve:

1) make the url in the browser bar change to the url without trailing slash

2) send the get url without the trailing slash

Comment: give example of link before and after redirection !

Comment: before: domain.com/search/term/ after: domain.com/search/term

Answer (score 0):

This line should do what you want :

```
RewriteRule ^search/term/(.*)/$ search/term/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: this does not work with the above line in my question to produce the desired results

Comment: what this produce ? this line will change search/term/anything/ to seach/term/anything is that what you want ?